# Present transparent UIView with opaque UIButton or UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimage, presentviewcontroller

I am trying to make a transparent `UIView` when using `presentViewController`. The problem is that the `UIButton` or `UIImageView` always are transparent, how can I make them non-transparent?

```
targetViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"newViewController"];

targetViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;

[self presentViewController:targetViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJjBv.png

I want `UIButton` or `UIImageView` to be opaque. How can I do it?

Comment: How did you make transparent? Set alpha. Did you try with clear backgroundcolor?

Comment: I try clear background color and add alpha view. It's work! thanks a lot

Comment: Nice. I will write an answer for others can refer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using UIView's alpha, using clear backgroundColor

```
targetViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```